# how to send querystring in anchor tag in datalist item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

i want to add hyperlink and pass query string of two columns details. unable to add coloumn in query string in asp.net datalist itemtemplate

```
 <asp:DataList
        id="datalistleads"

        RepeatColumns="1"
        GridLines="Both"
        Runat="server" BackColor="#D9EDF7" Width="333px">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <a href="Leads1.aspx?company=<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>&Contactperson=<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>">     <br />

        Contact Person:
        <%#Eval("ContactPerson") %>
        <br />
      </a>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to add column in querystring?" Do you get any errors/exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your anchor tag to following it should work:-

```
<a href='Leads1.aspx?company=<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:DataList
        id="datalistleads"

        RepeatColumns="1"
        GridLines="Both"
        Runat="server" BackColor="#D9EDF7" Width="333px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="Leads1.aspx?company=<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>&Contactperson=<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>">        <br />
        <b><%#Eval("CompanyName")%>,</b>

        Contact Person:
        <%#Eval("ContactPerson") %>
        <br />
      </a>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```